# Controls with a collection use the incorrect styling with value types

Tags: c#, wpf, value-type, itemssource, reference-type

Controls with collections in WPF (e.g. `ListBox` or `ComboBox`) use `TextBlock` styling instead of their own when using value types (like `int` or `enum`).

**Verifiable example:**

*Xaml code:*

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="cbb1" Margin="0 -100 0 0"/>
    <ComboBox Name="cbb2"/>
</Grid>
```

*CS code:*

```
//In the constructor
cbb1.ItemsSource = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
cbb1.SelectedItem = cbb1.Items[0];

cbb2.ItemsSource = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
cbb2.SelectedItem = cbb2.Items[0];
```

---

This example code will show 2 `ComboBox`'s, one where the items have the 'incorrect' `TextBlock` styling and the other will have the 'normal' `ComboBox` styling.

Other then making a class for needed value types (most commonly `enum`s for me) or removing the style is there a workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an ItemTemplate with a TextBlock, which does not use the default TextBlock Style:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Interesting, and strange. Would you have any idea why it differentiates between value and reference type (in terms of styling)?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. You could check the implementation of ContentPresenter in the .Net Reference Source.